# push_back copy objects even for temps although stating otherwise in it's definition?

Tags: c++, vector, push-back, copy-elision

one of push_back definition is

```
  push_back(const value_type& __x)
```

so Having  `my_vector2.push_back( obj );` will result in passing object obj by reference( No copy during passing object) still it call the copy constructor in the body of push_back somewhere so why not just pass it by value ie;

```
  push_back(const value_type  __x)
```

and make behavior of it understandable from just reading the function prototype. I dont know if copy elision will step in since it's supposed for return values only and constructors dont return anything. So would in any case copy-elision step in during passing of objects to functions or methods in any way or is it  for return values only. I mean elision a copy of an object passed by value to a function(push_back) or whatever so we we have to make a copy in the body of push_back?

second thing that's Even more confusing it also take a copy of a Temporary and same behavior as above it take it by rvalue reference `push_back(value_type&& __x)` so why take a copy of an already temporary object. I mean I dont need it (it's a temp) I know there is point a miss here but what is it.

Comment: Are you asking "why copy once when you could copy twice"?

Comment: RValue references allow for lighter-weight move-semantics -- this isn't just for temporary objects. Moves are different from copies. Some things are move-only, and the `&&` overload is the only available `push_back` (for example, `unique_ptr`).

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont No I mean if it want to copy why not pass by value and use this object and just store this object I mean would there be a difference (is it because the pass by value can be elided by the compiler or it just decided to use this approach so a matter of preferences )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`push_back` predates move semantics, so the best `std::vector` can do is copy.  While it could have changed with C++11, this would also be a change of behavior, which might break code in some cases (weird cases, but still valid ones).

If you want to avoid copies when dealing with temporaries, then you actually want `emplace_back`, which does exactly what you're describing.  It will construct the object in place in the `vector`'s storage, so your overhead if passing a temporary is a move ctor.